# Failed to resolve Intent Service Android

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, intentservice

I am getting following error when trying to configure Push Notification:

```
06-07 01:05:59.735 18708-18708/com.ebr.apps.ebr.development E/FirebaseInstanceId: Failed to resolve target intent service, skipping classname enforcement
06-07 01:05:59.735 18708-18708/com.ebr.apps.ebr.development E/FirebaseInstanceId: Error while delivering the message: ServiceIntent not found.
```

I have different flavors in gradle:

My code package name is : **com.ebr.apps.ebr**
My product flavor package is: **com.ebr.apps.ebr.development**

I have placed  google-services.json in **app/src/development**

**Manifest:**

```
    <permission
        android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>

         <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name=".GCM.PushNotificationService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

I have looked at many example but still getting this error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the solution, the problem was that Instabug GCMListener was conflicting with my GCMListener. I set the priority of my gcm listener and it started working.

```
<service
    android:name=".GCM.PushNotificationService"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter android:priority="10000">
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Comment: You should tag this as an Accepted Answer. :)

Comment: The documentation says "The value must be greater than -1000 and less than 1000." So is `10000` on purpose? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/IntentFilter.html#SYSTEM_HIGH_PRIORITY

Answer (score 2):

If your coming from a search engine: you might have as well run into this bug, which affects also the current version com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.8.0

https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/72

It was not yet possible to reproduce the bug and it is not fully understood how the situation can happen but you might be interested in following the thread.