# Android FCM with Azure Notification Hubs Error FirebaseInstanceId

Tags: android, azure, android-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, azure-notificationhub

Notification works fine I see message but when I recived notification I had 2 error message:

```
E/FirebaseInstanceId: Failed to resolve target intent service, skipping classname enforcement
E/FirebaseInstanceId: Error while delivering the message: ServiceIntent not found.
```

Manifest

```
  <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        tools:replace="android:icon"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <service
            android:name=".MyInstanceIDListenerService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <receiver android:name="com.microsoft.windowsazure.notifications.NotificationsBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="com.example.xxx.notificationandriodfcm" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
```

depnds:

```
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.microsoft.azure:notification-hubs-android-sdk:0.4@aar'
    compile 'com.microsoft.azure:azure-notifications-handler:1.0.1@aar'

repositories {
    maven {
        url "http://dl.bintray.com/microsoftazuremobile/SDK"
    }
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I based code on this tutorial:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-android-push-notification-google-fcm-get-started/

Any idea what can be wrong ? What should I do ?

Comment: Looks like you are mixing a few things here, FCM, GCM and Notification-Hub. It would be helpful if you could isolate those technologies and see if you get the issue. I'd recommend starting with the FCM sample (https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/messaging). The setup is much easier than GCM and you can still use Azure Notification Hub. Mixing GCM and FCM is not recommended, so I'd try FCM only with Notification hub.

Answer (score 0):

If you're completely sure the manifest is correct, it is possible that you're hitting an Android bug that [Google is working on to fixing now](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/72). If you can reliably reproduce the issue, let them know in the thread.

But before you do, take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37666996/182371) to see if it helps.

Also, if you can, try to run the app on another device or emulator version. If you do not see error messages on another device, then it's possible you were hitting the bug originally. If you still see them, then it's most likely some sort of generic issue. Try [searching for a solution](https://www.google.com/search?q=Failed%20to%20resolve%20target%20intent%20service%2C%20skipping%20classname%20enforcement).

Answer (score 0):

@wroe12, There is the Android [sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-notificationhubs-samples/tree/master/Android/GetStartedFirebase) with Azure Notification Hubs in Firebase which you followed the code from the tutorial. Please git clone it and try to check via comparing with your code to find out the key of the issue.

Hope it helps.