# Android FCM Error FirebaseInstanceId: Error while delivering the message: ServiceIntent not found

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

FCM Notification working when app is open but when I am closing app and removing it from recent apps, notification working for 30 sec or 1 min after that when I sending notification it not working and showing error in logcat

```
FirebaseInstanceId: Error while delivering the message: ServiceIntent not found.
```

Comment: Are you talking about upstreaming message from the device or downstreaming message from the server/other sources?

Comment: downstreaming message

Comment: so does this mean the `onMessageReceived` on the device is still called, but somehow it still doesn't work? I'm not quite clear on what exactly the situation is.

Comment: No, onMessageReceived on the device not called

Comment: so does this error come from the sending side, or is the app still responding when got a message but just responding with this error message? If it's the latter, I suspect that there's something wrong with the message you are sending. Are you sending data messages or normal messages?

Comment: i think it is from device side by os or something else

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191140/discussion-between-jackz314-and-anil).

Comment: i am sending data message

Comment: yes I am getting Background start not allowed: service Intent { act=com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT

Comment: The xiaomi device could be the problem, try testing your app on a close to vanilla Android device or an emulator that has Google services installed

Answer (score -1):

First, make sure you have added the dependency to firebase messaging and
 your receiver correctly as the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client) suggests:

In app module's build.gradle:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:the-version
```

And in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<service
    android:name=".java.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

If you are using `GCM`, It's also mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37666056/failed-to-resolve-intent-service-android) that you need to set high priority to your gcm listener:

```
<service
    android:name=".GCM.PushNotificationService"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter android:priority="10000">
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```